# Get user current time zone in php

Tags: php

I want to know, how can i get the current timezone in php.
I am using Wordpres Cms and want to filter out the product listing based on the timezone.

Let me know if there is any other alternative as well.

Thanks

Comment: https://eval.in/872394

Answer (score 1):

Use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) library. It's great when it comes to knowing the timezone

```
var tz = moment.tz.guess();
```

You will get a good name for the timezone, like *Europe/Berlin* for CET.

And [all browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization) the API on which moment.js relies.